# Change default gateway for specific program?

Tags: debian, networking, routing, exim

I have a machine hosted in datacenter with 3 network interfaces.

```
Interface  network         ip address
eth0       192.168.1.0/24  192.168.1.10
eth1       192.168.2.0/24  192.168.2.10
eth2       192.168.3.0/24  192.168.3.10
```

My default gateway is set to 192.168.2.1, where I can access some services provided by datacenter (repositories, ntp and so on).

Network 192.168.1.0/24 has a gateway at 192.168.1.1 through which I can access outside world, where dragons live. When I need to go out of my server I simply add a static route. I kind of like this setting as I know where my server is connecting.

Now, I have a mail client (exim4) which needs to send mails... to anyone. So ideally it needs to have a default gw set to 192.168.1.1. Is there a way to route only traffic for this particular service or should I simply change my network configuration on the server?

I'm on debian 8 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the firewall (iptables) to route to a specific gateway depending on one of 3 characteristics: destination port, source port or owner (may not work, see below)

First you will add a custom routing table for your special application (gateway 192.168.1.1), create a rule that redirect all packages with the mask `1` to this table, and create a iptables rule that masque the source address in case the package was redirected:

```
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 table 1
ip route add 0/0 via 192.168.1.1 table 1
ip rule add fwmark 1 table 1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.10
```

---

For the package marking you have 3 options:

Redirect by destination port, charging PORT with the server port used by exim:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport PORT -j MARK --set-mark 4
```

Redirect by source port, charging PORT with the port used locally by exim, if it does use only one source port:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport PORT -j MARK --set-mark 4
```

Redirect by Owner, changing OWNER with the PID from the Exim process (see `iptables -m owner --help` for other options):

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --pid-owner OWNER -j MARK --set-mark 4
```

---

Redirecting by Owner considerations [www.frozentux.net](https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html#OWNERMATCH):

```
The pid, sid and command matching is broken in SMP kernels since they use different process lists for each processor. It might be fixed in the future however
```

So depending on your kernel this feature is unavailable or broken (will not work properly)

Comment: The owner method is totally new for me. And i would use that if I had another kernel. I will see if I can use source port but I doubt it.

Comment: I guess you can use the destination ports right? smtp will use just 25, 465, and 587 I think.

Comment: The number used in iptables `--set-mark` should be the same from ip rule `fwmark`, just a typo.